# Git - how to verify if and where Git is installed on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and Git. How I can verify that I have installed git on my machine? When I tried apt-get I got:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/nebojsa# apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-39 linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-40 linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-43 linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
```

but I don't know where are the packages installed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're asking two different question: how to verify that `git` is installed, and *where* it's installed.

Comment: @KeithThompson apparently there is one answer to both questions.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Type `which git`.  It should return the path to the executable

If you want to see more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/96964/list-of-files-installed-from-apt-package

Answer (score 24):

Just call the `git --version`. It should return something like this:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

Answer (score 7):

Like most executables, `git` is installed in `/usr/bin/git`.

To see where all the files that are part of the `git` package are located, you can type:

```
dpkg -L git
```

You'll want to pipe the output through `less` or your favorite page; I get <strike>591</strike> 664  lines of output on my system.

(Not all systems use the same package manager that Ubuntu does. You might need to use some command other than `dpkg`, perhaps `rpm`, `yum` or `dnf`.)

If you had installed git from source rather than via the package manager, the `git` executable could be anywhere, depending on how you installed it. If it's in your `$PATH`, typing

```
type git
```

or

```
type -a git
```

would tell you where it is. (That's assuming you're using the default bash shell.)

Answer (score 4):

`which git` is the command to use , this gives the location where git is installed if it is already installed , usually  `/usr/bin/git` .If git isn't installed u wont be getting any thing.[image: when git is already installed]

Answer (score 1):

It tells you

```
git is already the newest version.
```

so everything should be OK.

Tip: to see files installed by a package, run

```
dpkg -L git
```

It will list a lot of files, but the most important one is `/usr/bin/git`. Another command, `which git`, returns what file exactly is being run when you run `git` - it should be the same.

Comment: `type git` is more reliable if you're running bash. It's built into the shell, so it  can show aliases and function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, git is installed. As for your question about the location of the package, this is most likely rather irrelevant for you. If you find yourself browsing a linux filesystem just to execute a program that has been installed system-wide, something is off. You don't usually need to do that at all.

As for git, opening the terminal  and typing 'git' will give you the basics. More can be read typing 'man git' (man command is good for finding additional info on a package).

If you want a graphical front-end for git, see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/227554/what-are-some-gui-clients-for-git